# Retrieve a type from a string known at compile time

Tags: c++, templates

Is it possible to get a type according to a `string` known at compile time?
Mainly with `constexpr std::string_view`.

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

template <std::string_view> 
struct MakeType {};

template <> 
struct MakeType<"int"> {
    using type = int;
};

template <> 
struct MakeType<"float"> {
    using type = float;
};


int  main() {
  constexpr std::string_view my_int = "int";
  MakeType<my_int>::type i = 5;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, C++ does not work this way. By the way: which C++ textbook told you to use a non-standard header file, like this? You should throw away that textbook, it's teaching you non-standard, non-portable C++, and get a better textbook.

Comment: Since the string is known at compile time, why do you even need this?

Comment: I use this header when I do tests, everything is included so it's easier.
I don't use it in "real code".

I will do otherwise, thank you for your answers

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: There is a solution to do such hacks, even if the sense is may be unclear... take a look at my answer please :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do such things, even if I currently did not see why we need it. But it did not work on base of `std::string_view` as we need a data type which contains the data in the object itself. As C++20 offers a simple way to define a constexpr string type via template parms, we have all what we need!

```
template<size_t N>
struct mystring
{
    std::array<char, N> arr_;

    constexpr mystring(const char(&in)[N]) : arr_{}
    {   
        std::copy(in, in + N, arr_.begin());
    }   
};


template < mystring s > struct MakeType { using type=void;};
template <> struct MakeType<"int"> {using type=int;};
template <> struct MakeType<"double"> {using type=double;};

template < mystring T>
using MakeType_t = MakeType<T>::type;

int main()
{
    MakeType_t<"int"> xi=9;
    MakeType_t<"double"> xd=10.234;

    std::cout << xi << std::endl;
    std::cout << xd << std::endl;

    static_assert( std::is_same_v< double, MakeType_t<"double">>);
    static_assert( std::is_same_v< int, MakeType_t<"int">>);
}
```

[See it working here on gcc ...](https://godbolt.org/z/rET8sWGrT)
[also for clang](https://godbolt.org/z/9Ed43v9rb)

Remark: clang requires an additional `typename`. I believe clang is wrong here, as in C++20 the need of additional `typename` was relaxed a lot, but I am not a language-lawyer.